# C# How to pass arguments to service on runtime?

Tags: c#, batch-file, service, command

I have a scenario here that requires using `.bat` batch files to pass some arguments to the `OnCustomCommand` method for `service` application. Is this a possible way to do so? I had tried to use `app.config` but that would be abit troublesome to edit the `app.config` file everytime i need to run the `service` command. Please advise, thank you!

Comment: So you are trying to execute a application and give it arguments? and you run the application from a bat file?

Comment: I am trying to have a service that is runs in the background and when i use a batch file to execute a service custom command, it carries out a specific function. But for this specific function, I need certain arguments to determine which files are involved.